# MySQL Query suggestions - column vs joint

Tags: mysql, performance, join, left-join

We have a user table like this - with over 20 million entries.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) default '',
  `email` varchar(64) default '',
  `flag` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In our admin panel, we'd like to show a few pinned users and search results from the user table.

There are two approaches we thought to show pinned user (pls suggest if any other better approaches)

1) add a separate column in user table for pinned users. However, pinned users are a handful (less than 100) compared to the total number of users (> 20M). Hence, this approach doesn't appear promising.

2) a separate table of pinned users and use join,

```
CREATE TABLE `pinnedusers` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default 0,
   PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and run a join, for example,

```
select * 
from users 
left join pinnedusers 
    on pinnedusers.uid=users.uid 
order by pinnedusers.uid desc 
limit 200;
```

However, we are worried about the performance of the second approach as it involves join, order, limit.

What do you suggest?

Comment: The second approach.

Comment: Does the `flag` determine if the users' pinned or not? If not, have a `pinned` bit field and index it or use the second approach. Use the pinnedusers table as your base table though with an inner join.

Comment: Should be _join_ instead of _joint_. The 2nd approach would be the preferred method, and as long as you have the proper columns indexed, performance should not be a problem. I would use the pinnedusers as the from table, and join (not left join) to the users table.

Comment: Jonathon, logical 'AND' query can't be indexed.

Comment: @Sloan could you pls elaborate, wouldn't join restrict to common entries only? We used left join so that non-matching entries from users table can be shown below matched (pinned) entries. Maybe I am missing something from your reply.

Comment: @yumoji I wasn't suggesting a logical `AND`. Your second approach with `from pinnedusers inner join users on users.uid = pinnedusers.uid` is the way to go.

Comment: I think you should be having a user wise settings. I would recommend a row,  a master entry having pinned users as the name in usersettings master and the reference in the other table say usersettings columns having values as comma separated userids.

Comment: @JonathonOgden maybe I missed something in your reply then. Flag can accommodate 'pinned' as a bit field but how do you suggest to use it then without using logical 'AND'

Comment: @yumoji ah, apologies. The `flag` question was just a general question as I wasn't sure if you were already identifying pinned users using the flags.

Comment: If you want pinned users and non-pinned users, you'll need a way to be sure the pinned users are included. ie. sorted so they're at the top of the results. Also, the suggestion to use pinnedusers in the from and users in the join presumed you only wanted pinned users and would improve performance. If you want non-pinned users, ignore that comment.

Comment: @SloanThrasher  yes we need both, first pinned users and then unpinned.

Comment: just wondering, why would someone downvote this questions saying no research or not clear.  I am just brainstorming with other knowledgeable users.

Comment: No idea why this was down-voted. I wish people were required to indicate the reason when they down-vote an question or answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should produce the results you want, and indicate which rows are "pinned" users.

```
SELECT 
    a.*,
    IF(b.`id` IS NULL,0,1) as `is_pinned`
FROM users a
LEFT JOIN pinnedusers b
    on b.uid = a.uid 
ORDER BY IF(b.`id` IS NULL,0,1) DESC, a.uid DESC
LIMIT 200;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `JOIN` to fear, it's the need to scan the entire 20M rows.

To "show a few pinned users", use this to "show up to 200 pinned users":

```
SELECT u.*
    FROM pinnedusers p
    JOIN users u  USING(uid)
    ORDER BY ...
    LIMIT 200;
```

If there are fewer than 200 pinned users, the list will have less than 200.  But the query will be fast.

Your original query and Sloan's are both terribly slow because they will have to scan the entire 20M rows (assuming less than 200 are pinned).

If you want all the pinned users, *plus* enough non-pinned users to fill out a list of 200, that is a different task.  But, *which* non-pinned users would you like?  The first few?  That would be quick.  A random few?  That is more complex, else it, too, would scan the entire 20M.  Some other criteria?